# ASP.NET 2.0 Force SSL from a control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl

First of all I want to say that any solution I come up with has to work for .NET 2.0 as that's the framework my project is targeting.

I have an ASP.NET web site that I use code to force pages into SSL or not, not the web.config.  Basically every page is forced into non-SSL unless a page inherits an Interface I've created that allows the page to define a property to force SSL. I have a method that runs on page load and looks to see if the page inherits this Interface and then checks the value of this property.  This works all fine and good for us, but I'd like to extend this type of functionality to custom Server or User Controls.

I originally looked at just having the control use the same interface, but I quickly found out that recursively looking through all the Page's control collection is time consuming and can cause stack overflow if the nesting is too deep.

Next I looked at trying to create an Attribute that I could use to decorate the control and run some logic in Attribute's CTOR, but this failed as I couldn't consistently force the Attribute's CTOR to run, as I'd have to call the GetCustomAttributes() method on the control, which takes me back to recursion and the problems there.

Does anyone know of a way I can "decorate" a class with an interface, attribute or the like and tie that into some logic that I can run consistently when the class is instantiated, in .NET 2.0?  I think I have confirmed that I can use the Page's Items collection (or the HttpContext's Items collection) to store a "ForceSSL" value that I can then look for on page load and rewrite the URL as needed. The trick I'd like to figure out is to how to trigger this simply.

I realize I could just have a global method like Organization.Global.Utilities.ForceSSL() that does this type of thing, but I was hoping there was some sort of "decoration" type pattern I could use to invoke this logic/method.

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

What about having the control check it's parent page?

```
this.Page
```

Then determine if it's of a type requires SSL then redirect, force 403, etc.

This is odd behavior for a control tho.